# Are there any Email Saas providers which allows creation of email ids using APIs?

Tags: email, sendgrid, mail-server, mailgun, cloudmailin

For a project I need to setup either a **mail server (like Open X-change, Kolab)** or I can use email service as **Saas from providers like Mailgun, Sendgrid etc**. But my prime requirements are:

1. Create new email addresses using (Rest) API or any other API programmatically.
2. Ability to create huge number of email ids (more than 10,000)

I have researched and found some like mailgun provides facility of sending / receiving messages through APIs. But nothing was mentioned about creating new email ids using APIs.

Does anyone know any mail server / SaaS which provides the aforementioned facilities?

Answer (score 0):

To have a mail id, you need to be able to accept messages at that location, which would be a full mail service such as Gmail.

If you just need to send "as" addresses, you can use an SMTP service such as SendGrid. You'd just need to make sure the domain is legitimate and can receive mail, and that you set the Reply-To value to something that you can accept mail at.